# Error Installing capybara-webkit 1.11.1 with native extensions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Error:

```
Installing capybara-webkit 1.11.1 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/capybara-webkit-1.11.1
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160607-31306-ngtugv.rb extconf.rb
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --with-gl-dir
        --without-gl-dir
        --with-gl-include
        --without-gl-include=${gl-dir}/include
        --with-gl-lib
        --without-gl-lib=${gl-dir}/lib
        --with-zlib-dir
        --without-zlib-dir
        --with-zlib-include
        --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
        --with-zlib-lib
        --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
Command 'qmake ' not available

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/capybara-webkit-1.11.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/capybara-webkit-1.11.1/gem_make.out
```

Comment: did you install QT?

"capybara-webkit depends on a WebKit implementation from Qt, a cross-platform development toolkit. You'll need to download the Qt libraries to build and install the gem. You can find instructions for downloading and installing QT on the capybara-webkit wiki. capybara-webkit requires Qt version 4.8 or greater."

Comment: Refer this based on the os you are using, https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/wiki/Installing-Qt-and-compiling-capybara-webkit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to be lacking the Qt libraries on your computer. There's a nice [tutorial](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/wiki/Installing-Qt-and-compiling-capybara-webkit) on the capybara-webkit github page showing how to install it.

Answer (score 0):

This gem has some dependencies, you need to install them to make it work. you can do it with this.

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install g++ qt5-default libqt5webkit5-dev gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-tools gstreamer1.0-x
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//s.tk/meta/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!